# how do i get the top 20 most searched query in elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have stored sentences in elasticsearch for autosuggestion.

format:

```
{
  "text": "what is temperature in chicago"
}
```

it suggests correctly when w or wha or what typed. but I am wondering if there is any way I can fetch most search sentences from elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregations:

Your request body should look something like this:

```
        {
            "query": {
                //your query
            },
            "aggs": {
                "common" : {
                    "terms" : { "field" : "text.keyword", "size": 20 }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you want most common searches done wrt to input query, a simple solution can be implemented.
Just track what user finally selects (document of ES) and then increment its counter by 1 keeping mapping of _id.
Running a batch system/sync/indexing this data in ES data will have counter value in your data.
Use this while giving suggestions i.e sort with count field.
This will start working properly as users start using.
Your ES document would look like.

```
{    "text":"what is temperature in chicago",
     "count":10

}
```

I would suggest this is very raw solution there can be many, but nice to start with.